# Does spark load all data from Kudu when a filter is used?

Tags: apache-spark, kudu

I am new to spark. Will the following code load all data or just filter data from kudu?

```
val df: DataFrame = spark.read.options(Map(
   "kudu.master" -> kuduMaster,
   "kudu.table" -> s"impala::platform.${table}")).kudu

val outPutDF = df.filter(row => {
     val recordAt: Long = row.getAs("record_at").toString.toLong
     recordAt >= XXX && recordAt < YYY
   })
```

Comment: What do you conclude here yourself?

Comment: i finally found add where can pushed down to kudu,thank you all!
spark.read.options(Map( 
 "kudu.master" -> kuduMaster,
 "kudu.table" -> table)).kudu
 .where(s"record_at >= XXX and record_at < XXX")

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to check if the filter is pushed down or not for a given connector is **using Spark UI**.
The scan nodes in Spark will have the metrics of number of records read from the datasource.(You can check this Spark UI -> SQL tab, ater running a query)
Write a query with and without an explicit predicate(on a small dataset).

**Inferences**
1. If the number of records in scan node is the same with and without predicate - Spark has read the data completely from datasource and filtering will be done in Spark.
2. If the numbers are different, predicate pushdown has been implemented in the datasource connector.
3. Using this experiment you could also figure which kinds of predicates are pushed down.(depends on connector implementation)

Comment: `explain` will show if the filter is pushed down, based on the way the `toString` of scan node is implemented. We will come to know if it was really pushed down, from the metrics shown in SQL tab of Spark Ui, after the execution(or by looking into source code of connector).

Comment: I quote from the manuals as well, but the notion of easier is debatable.

Answer (score 0):

Try .explain.

Not sure I got the code, but here is an example of some code that works.

```
val dfX = df.map(row => XYZ{row.getAs[Long]("someVal")}).filter($"someVal" === 2)
```

But assuming you can get code to work, Spark "predicate pushdown" will apply in your case and filtering in Kudu Storage Manager applied. So, not all data loaded.

This is from the KUDU Guide:

> <> and OR predicates are not pushed to Kudu, and instead will be
>   evaluated by the Spark task. Only LIKE predicates with a suffix
>   wildcard are pushed to Kudu, meaning that LIKE "FOO%" is pushed down
>   but LIKE "FOO%BAR" isn’t.

That is to say, your case is OK.